# How to scroll to top using JQuery and Material-Design-Lite

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, material-design-lite

I've been using Material-Design-Lite in my website and I'm also using JQuery to display a button that scrolls to top. But they are not working together. With Material-Design-Lite installed, the button does nothing on click.

```
<div class='back-to-top'>
  <a class='hvr-icon-spin' href='#'/>
</div>

<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() &gt; 200) {
      $(&#39;#back-to-top&#39;).fadeIn();
        } else {
        $(&#39;#back-to-top&#39;).fadeOut();
        }
        });
      $(&#39;#back-to-top&#39;).hide().click(function() {
        $(&#39;html, body&#39;).animate({scrollTop:0}, 600);
        return false;
        });
</script>
```

Is there any alternative way to solve it? I've tried not using JQyery, but it also didn't work. The website I'm trying to use it is [here.](http://testes-hitsebeats.blogspot.com.br/)

Answer (score 2):

This might happen due to fixed position of your main container, header. And material design uses overflow in mdl container. So use this code to scroll top:

```
$(".mdl-layout__content").animate({scrollTop:0}, 500, "slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use

```
$('.mdl-layout__content').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

http://jsfiddle.net/6qrQF/88/

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //set the link
  jQuery('#top-link').topLink({
    min: 500,
    fadeSpeed: 100
  });
  //smoothscroll
  jQuery('#top-link').click(function(r) {    
    jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 300);
  });
});
```

Comment: When you include MDL, the button still doesn't appear. Check the code here (http://jsfiddle.net/6qrQF/97/), and fully 'working' here (https://jsfiddle.net/6qrQF/97/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with:

```
$('.mdl-layout').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
```